# How to Install PyHDF package on Google Colab?

Tags: python, bigdata, google-colaboratory, hdf, pyhdf

I tried `!pip install pyhdf`, 
Referred this too. http://stream.princeton.edu/AWCM/LIBRARIES/pyhdf-0.8.3/doc/webpage/source/install.html
no luck. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this, but I did the following and it worked.

```
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-numpy libhdf4-dev -y

pip install git+https://github.com/hdfeos/pyhdf.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you an use [gohlke's](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhdf) package.

Comment: This is a jupyter notebook hosted on Google servers.
you can view the environment here.
http://colab.research.google.com